# Showing Unnecessary border in panel in MVC with Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design two panels in same line, its work but showing unnecessary border,
Here is xyz.cshtml code with Bootstrap,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading">Add Members</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <button id="btnAddMem" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">ADD</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">

    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-4">
        <div class="panel-heading">Add Others</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <button id="btnAddOther" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">ADD</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And output looks like this image,
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try this code,

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
       ...
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1">

     </div>
     <div  class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
         ...
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

you have added col-md-4 with panel.it will put padding so thats why it will add extra border in your output.
So I have remove it from panel div and added as parent.

Comment: Than I will suggest you that you need to do change in css of panel to remove your border.

Comment: add style in panel div tag like this  <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-4 " style="border:none;">